# Connect to VPN from Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, vpn, azure-virtual-network

We have a SMS provider that gives us access to their SMPP Server. The only problem is that, for security reasons (estipulated by this provider), we need to use a VPN connection. That is: once there (in their net) we can access the smpp server using a local IP address (10.x.x..)

**Can I do this in Windows Azure? Connect to their net using the Virtual Networks feature?**

Comment: have you found an answer for this?

Comment: No, I had to use Amazon instead (AWS)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late as answer, but I don't see the difference here regardless to AWS - in both cases you will VPN with their site. On Azure, you can definitely create a Site-to-Site VPN Gateway then establish VPN connectivity with the provider's site.